# Hide Rows with same serial_nr, if filtered in first sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA for a packing order sheet:

I'm trying to hide the rows in different sheets that have the same serial_nr as the ones that have been filtered (thus hidden) in the first sheet.

Because the rows are not the same over the different sheets, I try to use the serial_nr. But I can't seem to link the serial_nr value as a condition for the selection of the rows to hide in the other sheets.

In the end I broke it down to the most simple code i could get without errors but it doesn't work.

```
Sub Filter_over_multiple_sheets()

    Dim Serial_nr As Integer
    Dim Row_nr As Integer

    For Row_nr = 3 To 1020

        If Worksheets("Raaplijst").Cells(Row_nr, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
       Worksheets("Boutenlijst Kist B").Cells(Row_nr, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True    
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm still a newbie to VBA so I'm lost in all the approaches and combinations that are possible.

Anyone of you who could help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, for which you have to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference to your project in order to exploit `Dictionary` class

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter_over_multiple_sheets()
    Dim IDsDict As New Dictionary
    Dim rng As Range

    With Worksheets("Raaplijst") '<--| consider "mother" worksheet
        For Each rng In .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through column "A" non empty cells from row 3 down to last non empty one
            If rng.EntireRow.Hidden Then If Not IDsDict.Exists(CStr(rng.Value)) Then IDsDict.Add CStr(rng.Value), rng.Value '<--| if row is hidden add its ID to dictionary provided it's not been added already
        Next rng
    End With

    If IDsDict.Count > 0 Then '<--| go on if there's been at least one hidden row ID
        With Worksheets("Boutenlijst Kist B") '<--| consider "child" worksheet
            With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| loop through column "A" cells fom row 2 (header) down to last non empty one
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=(IDsDict.Keys), Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter column "A" with IDs corresponding with "mother" worksheet hidden rows
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell has been filtered...
                    Set rng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| ... store filtered cells in a range variable...
                    .AutoFilter '<--| .. show all rows back...
                    rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True '<--| ... and hide only just stored cells rows
                Else '<--| otherwise
                    .AutoFilter '<--| .. show all rows back...
                End If
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work beautifully. The code is understandeble aswell allthough I'm not yet farmiliar with the dictionary functions. I've read into it and understand what it does. Very usefull.

I can deffinitly use this and work on it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you have the best method to use, its the simplest. Just a couple of things, your Serial_nr variable isn't used, its probably best to fix the indentation on your if statement, it makes for much easier reading especially in long pieces of code, and finally use .Rows instead of .Cells

```
Sub Filter_over_multiple_sheets()
```

`Dim Row_nr As Integer

For Row_nr = 3 To 1020

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(Row_nr).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(Row_nr).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
End Sub`

Comment: Thanks Rabbitman, it looks a bit cleaner this way i agree. Ill try it.

Comment: To be fair, it depends what exactly you are doing, user3598756's answer is very explicit and can be useful in complicated situations, I'd say however if the problem is as simple as you stated, its not needed to be so needlessly complicated

Comment: Your simplified solution did not do the trick. It gives no errors but changes nothing in the sheet(do not know why). Also the comparison of the serial numbers ensures the correctness. Which is nice.
User3598756's solution did. Directory use is new to me so Ill have to look into that.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it works perfectly on my machine, what version of excel are you using? And did you change the sheet names back?

Comment: Also what is your Serial_nr referring to? a value of a particular cell in a row?

Comment: Excel 2013. Yes I did:) The tricky thing is that the cells all got references to other sheets which seems to interfere with vba functions. So my aim is to keep it as simple as possible but that often can't be done.

Comment: Yes, serial_nr is just a cell value given in column A that corresponds no matter what the row or sheet location is. (other guy started this massive workbook)

Comment: ok, well adding an "and Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row_nr, 1).Vaule = Serial_nr" to the IF statement should do the trick. If it doesn't because of inferring values causing issues, you can always copy the sheet out and paste special the values only and not the references. If neither of these are preferable then yeah, use the other solution

Comment: It seems flawless to me too. No choice but to stick with the complex solution. Thanks anyway Rabbitman!

Comment: No problem, if it did help, a vote would be nice :) I'm sure User would appreciate it too